# Do we have primary sources for what ordinary people used before mirrors became widely affordable?

Tags: everyday-life, everyday-objects

[Mirrors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror) are an everyday item with a very long history. However, until 200 or so years ago mirrors, at least large ones, were too expensive for ordinary people (ordinary in the sense of e.g. being not among the richest 20% or the poorest 20% of a given society).

One relatively obvious solution to the problem of not having a mirror would be to look into one's reflection on a water surface. According to my own  experiments at home, it is usually not as good as a mirror, but something one can work with under daylight conditions. And according to a trusted source, one can improve the clarity of the reflected image by choosing a more appropriate water container.

However, do we actually have sources for people doing this *inside or close to their houses*? Or is it true what is claimed [here](https://dustyoldthing.com/before-mirrors-were-invented/) and [here](https://www.fastcompany.com/3065643/how-the-invention-of-the-mirror-changed-everything), that people just did not really care what they looked like?

(I am familiar with descriptions of people seeing their face in the water from [Narcissus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(mythology)) and also from Goethe's poem [the Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Fischer_(Goethe)), but both of these are set outside the house, i.e. not in the place one would most often use a mirror nowadays)

Comment: The high society folk most concerned about their looks had servants to make them look their best.

Comment: I think it is not so much that 'people didn't care what they looked like', but that most people were unfamiliar with the concept of seeing an accurate image of yourself and using it to check your appearance.

Comment: @MCW the wp article says that "This silvering process [invented in 1835] was adapted for mass manufacturing and led to the greater availability of affordable mirrors." which implies that affordable mirrors were uncommon before then.

Comment: @MCW it is in the second sentence. "However, until 200 or so years ago mirrors, at least large ones, were too expensive for ordinary people"

Comment: Related Question [How do ancient Chinese "mirrors" such as these in the National Museum function?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/67944/16951)